Why Do Two NER Models with Different Training Data Yield Identical Results?
I've developed several versions of an NER model using spaCy to identify singers in file names. Despite making significant updates to the training corpus—comprising approximately 13,000 entries—and rebuilding each model from scratch, two of the latest model versions produce identical evaluation scores.
Here are the scores for the models in question:

Version 16:
{'token_acc': 1.0, 'token_p': 1.0, 'token_r': 1.0, 'token_f': 1.0, 
'ents_p': 0.90625, 'ents_r': 0.9666666666666667, 'ents_f': 0.9354838709677419, 
'speed': 18948.981384522544}


Version 18:
{'token_acc': 1.0, 'token_p': 1.0, 'token_r': 1.0, 'token_f': 1.0, 
'ents_p': 0.90625, 'ents_r': 0.9666666666666667, 'ents_f': 0.9354838709677419, 
'speed': 16183.215075303027}



Details:

The training corpus was updated significantly between versions.
Each version was built from scratch, not based on the previous version.
Intermediate versions and older models showed different results.

Given these factors, why might these two versions, despite their different training data and significant updates, produce identical evaluation scores?

Depending on your set up the probability that your two models have the same metrics may actually be not so tiny when two versions are evaluated on a small fixed set (e.g. Wolfram alpha says that your number 0.9666666666666667 looks like 29/30 and 0.90625 like 29/32. Do you just have 30 positive examples in your validation set?). A bug somewhere in your code is also quite possible.

Yes, I have a small test array of 30 samples, what is the recommended array size for f1 score testing?
